# Bash script: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Can someone help me figure out why i'm receiving this error, syntax error near unexpected token `do'. I have tried researching the answer but no luck so far. below is part of my code

```
while
do
if [[ "${ScanConfirm}" == "Y" ]]; then
    # use a for Loop to scan the chosen directory and for every non-MDF file in the directory it creates an MDF file in a temp-MDF directory
    XCOUNT=0
    echo
    echo "Scanning Directory.. this may take a few minutes"
    echo "*************************************************"
    echo
    export TEMP_MDF="${StartingDir}/MDF_${RANDOM}"
    mkdir -p ${TEMP_MDF}

    for FILE in `find ${Dir2Scan} -type f`
    do
    export ERRORFILE=${FILE}
    BASEFILE=`basename ${FILE}`
    BASEDIR=`dirname ${FILE}`

    # echo priority 50 >>"${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf" <----------- you can take out this arrow and uncomment this to put in priorities
    # echo categoryName=${Category} >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf" <----------- if you want the category you entered about to show up in MDF you need to uncomment the lines above this note
    echo objectName=${RANDOM}${RANDOM}_${NamePrefix}_${BASEFILE} >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo "<comments>" >>"${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo "${Comments}" >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo "</comments>" >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo "originalServer=${BASEDIR}">>"${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    # echo "originalPath=${BASEDIR}">>"${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    chaine=`basename ${BASEDIR}`
    # echo "sourceDestinationDIVAPath=${chaine}" >>"${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo >> "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    echo "<fileList>" >>"${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    mv "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}.mdf" "${TEMP_MDF}/${BASEFILE}_${RANDOM}.mdf"
    ERRORLEVEL=$?
    if [ ${ERRORLEVEL} -ne 0 ]; then
        Stop
    fi
    XCOUNT=$((${XCOUNT}+1))
    echo "${XCOUNT}/${OriginalCount} MDF Files Created ${BASEFILE}.mdf"
    done
```

Comment: `while` what? You need to give `while` something to test to see how often it should do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Plus it seems that you're missing at least one `done` and one `fi`

Comment: Also consider using http://shellcheck.net/ for automated analysis before asking here. There's a lot more wrong with this script, and it would be silly for us to take the time to do it piece-by-piece, when shellcheck would give you all of it.

Comment: ...as it is, this is much more than the shortest code necessary to reproduce the individual problem you're asking about. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, don't put a `>>` with the same filename on each line. Every single redirection re-opens the output file -- meaning massive inefficiency compared to opening the file just once and keeping it open for as long as you need it. Much better to just put one `>"$TEMP_MDF/$BASEFILE.mdf"` at the end of the whole loop (ie. at the `done`), or, if you want it to be created within a smaller block, to use `{` and `}` to create one, and to put the redirection on the `}`.

Comment: Also, don't use all-uppercase names for your own variables. Shell variables and environment variables share a namespace; conventions for that namespace are discussed in the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (fourth paragraph). Short form: User-defined variables should contain at least one lower-case character to avoid overriding system-impacting or shell-builtin variable names by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From `help while`:

> while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done

Neither `COMMANDS` is given as optional in the syntax.

---

If you want an infinite loop, consider:

```
while :; do
```

or

```
while true; do
```

...which are both semantically identical (both `:` and `true` are built-in commands which unconditionally exit with status 0).

Comment: Thank you. Adding while : fixed the issue